# MongoDB + ElasticSearch data model

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I did not last long have been working with nosql , I have one main table that stores a reference to the external table. for search I used elasticsearch and  me needed join (join tables)To obtain the desired information, but nosql does not use join. I found child / Parent solution, but it have their problems. There are any alternatives or better to change the structure, use nested objects?

Answer (score 2):

Nosql has some of disadvantages like **NoJoins**.To over come that we need to query two or three collections in mongodb.

**1)** To over come that we need perform join before you store.If you wanna calculate a stat from a set of data perform **mapReduce** and store in collections.

**2)** As said nested objects also more effective.If hard disk space id not an issue you can go with nested docs.But i mongodb you cant create a doc more size than **16mb**.

**Using Elasticsearch**

**3)** In ES if you want data form more than one index then you can go with **aliases**.
refer http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

**4)** And last the **parent child concept** in elastic search ..It may be look like complex.But it helps a lot.

If your **application is more write and less read** means perform **joins during reading**.Like quering two or more collection to get a single information

If your **application is more read and less write** performs **joins before storing documents**.Go with **nested objects is right choice** you will write once read with one call.It will reduce CU usage a lot..

HOpe it helsp..!